# Accessing two isolated subnets from a Linux box

Tags: linux, routing, subnet

I have a Linux box with two NICs, each connected to a different LAN:

```
LAN A: 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
LAN B: 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
```

The routers are:

```
RouterA: 192.168.1.1
RouterB: 192.168.2.1
```

The wireless access points are:

```
WAP-B1: 192.168.2.3
WAP-B2: 192.168.2.4
```

Linux NICs are:

```
NIC A: 192.168.1.2 (eth0) default gateway 192.168.1.1, metric 100
NIC B: 192.168.2.2 (eth1) metric 101
```

Here's an ASCII diagram:

```
+-------+                                                           +-------+ 
| ISP A |                                                           | ISP B |
+-------+                                                           +-------+ 
    |                                                                   |
+---------+      +-------+      +-----------+      +-------+      +-----------+ 
| RouterA | <--> | LAN A | <--> | Linux Box | <--> | LAN B | <--> | RouterB-1 |
+---------+      +-------+      +-----------+      +-------+      +-----------+ 
                                                                    |        |
                                                            +--------+      +--------+
                                                            | WAP-B1 |      | WAP-B2 |
                                                            +--------+      +--------+
```

I want all Internet traffic to go through LAN A and ISP A. I only connect this Linux box to LAN B so I can perform administration on devices on LAN-B, particularly RouterB and WAP-B1, WAP-B2. Therefore, I want only addresses 192.168.2.0/24 to be routed through NIC B (eth1). I want all other traffic routed through NIC A. I do not want hosts in either LAN to be able to connect to each other (or ping each other, etc.). I want LAN A and LAN B to remain isolated.

I connected the network cables, and things seem to work. I assume the routing metrics were established by the order in which I connected the cables. However, I'd like to know the right way to set up routing rules to ensure I maintain a working configuration.

UPDATE: In response to a comment, here is the output of `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
```

This is the routing table I would have guessed would be correct. (It's just a guess.)

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     192.168.2.1     255.255.255.0   UG    101    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

In NetworkManager > IPv4 > Routes, I checked "ignore automatically obtained routes" and I added this static route:
192.168.2.0, netmask: 255.255.255.0, gateway: 192.168.2.1, metric: 101

Here is the routing table that results from those changes.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     192.168.2.1     255.255.255.0   UG    101    0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

That doesn't look right to me, but today is the first day I have ever looked at routing tables.

UPDATE: I'm running Arch Linux and NetworkManager. However, I would prefer an answer based on commands like `ip address` and `ip route`.

UPDATE 2: Thanks to [@vaha](https://serverfault.com/users/376854/vaha)'s answer, here is the desired routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
```

I have not figured out how to create a persistent configuration that assures this routing table upon a reboot.

However, I can establish those routes manually using these steps:

1. In NetworkManager > IPv4 > Routes, check "ignore automatically obtained routes" for both interfaces.
2. `$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 metric 100 dev eth0`
3. `$ sudo ip route delete default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1`

Other variants on this, such as not checking "ignore automatically obtained routes" for eth0 have not worked. For example, when I only ignored automatically obtained routes for eth1, upon boot, my system used 192.168.2.1 as the default gw. That is an unexpected and confusing result.

**My last question is how to configure my system so that these are the default routes after a reboot?**

Comment: Can you share output of route command?

Comment: @vaha the question has been updated. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on the order in which the interfaces are brought up to decide which gateway will be used. Instead you should change the configuration for `eth1` in such a way that no default route will be created when that interface is brought up. How to do that will depend on distribution.

Comment: @MountainX I don't know how to configure NetworkManager on a server as I have only seen that used on client machines. When configured through the UI the setting to look for would be *Ignore automatically obtained routes*.

Comment: @kasperd - I did choose that option. See bottom of my question. If you can give me an answer based on commands using just `ip address` and `ip route` I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @MountainX You shouldn't have added any routes manually, and somehow you also messed up the configuration for `eth0`. Your initial routing table was correct except from the superfluous default route. All you needed to do was to disable *Ignore automatically obtained routes* and leave everything else unchanged.

Comment: @kasperd I'm hoping to learn something about routing. If you want to provide an educational answer, I'll accept it. I would prefer an answer based on commands like `ip address` and `ip route`. Thanks

Comment: @kasperd I updated the question. Still trying to get this to persist correctly.

Comment: @MountainX Sounds like when you tried to ignore routes on one interface and not the other, you somehow got the interfaces configured backwards. You should try that again and include the resulting routing table.

Comment: @kasperd - yes, that's what it might sound like, but that's not what I actually did. I'll keep working on it and post an update in a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clear your concerns in two steps:

**STEP 1**

> Therefore, I want only addresses 192.168.2.0/24 to be routed through NIC B (eth1). I want all other traffic routed through NIC A.

The default routing table (the table before you manually configured) provides the routing rules you are looking for.

Here is the detailed explanation:

```
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
```

says that the subnet 192.168.2.0/24 is a local network and there is no need for a gateway. Any packet targeting an address in that network will be delivered to destination directly without a hop.

```
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

says the same thing for the subnet 192.168.1.0/24.

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
```

says that the remaining traffic will be routed through eth0 and eth1 where the routing decision depends on metric values. Lower metric value has a higher priority. **BUT** if eth0 is down then all traffic will be routed through eth1 and vice versa. By the way, I'm not sure but my best guess for eth0 having a higher priority than eth1 is the alphabetical order of the interface names.

As conclusion, the following table is what you are looking for. I'm not familiar with NetworkManager but I think you can ignore automatically obtained routes for both interfaces and manually set your owns to achieve this routing table.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
```

**STEP 2**

> I do not want hosts in either LAN to be able to connect to each other (or ping each other, etc.). I want LAN A and LAN B to remain isolated.

Simply connecting your linux box to two different networks has no effect on their isolation unless there is a NAT rule defined on the box's firewall or the box's interfaces are bridged.

You can check NAT rules via `iptables` or `nftables` which are tools to manage firewall on Arch Linux. Also see [Arch Linux wiki - Firewalls](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Category:Firewalls).

Example command to list NAT rules: `iptables -t nat -L -v -n`

No bridge is seen on your routing table but you can check bridges in details by using one of the ways described at [Arch Linux wiki - Network bridge](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge).

Comment: In NetworkManager > IPv4 > Routes, I checked "ignore automatically obtained routes" for both interfaces. Then I used these commands:  
`$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 metric 100 dev eth0`  
`$ sudo ip route delete default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1`  
The result is the routing table you recommended.  
How would I make this permanent (persistent across reboots)?

Comment: @MountainX, there is a folder named `/etc/network/if-up.d` in Debian where you can put your custom scripts for networking, but don't know what the corresponding way for it in Arch Linux is. I recommend you searching for that.

Comment: @MountainX The automatically generated routing table entries for `eth0` are already what you need, so there is no need to check *Ignore automatically obtained routes*  on `eth0`.

Comment: @kasperd I am still having to manually configure routing and I have not found out how to make it persistent. The automatically generated routing table entries are not correct.

Comment: @vaha - I appreciate your answer. I accepted it and upvoted it. Your comment would have been more appreciated if you hadn't started it with a snarky  "with a 5-sec search..." I'll respond to that part by saying that in your 5-sec search you apparently forgot that I am using NetworkManager, not dhcpcd (as mentioned in my question). Adding a static route for dhcpcd would do nothing for me. But I do appreciate your original answer, which was completely non-abrasive and very helpful.